# Reading Opera *dat files Objective C

Tags: objective-c, cookies, opera

I'm trying to read the Opera Cookie file, which has the *dat file extension. Opening the file in TextEdit reveals a mess...does anybody know how this file is composed and how I can open this using Objective-C?

**Edit:** I did find this: http://www.peeep.us/4899d1fa which reveals that they're created using a "general binary format". How can I read this?

Comment: I'm asking to the documentation team why these have disappeared. I might suspect two reasons: security and not up to date. I'll come back to you later with a proper answer.

Comment: thanks! let's hope that will reveal something!

Comment: Haven't heard from him, but I have cracked their file format myself.

Comment: ah sorry. Thanks for the reminder. I myself didn't have news/report on it. I'm opening a bug to track it at Opera.

Comment: Awesome! Their format can be taken apart in C, but it would be great if that documentation would reappear!

Comment: @david-schiefer In progress. Should be back soon :) It was a sync issue between docs evolution which had not been noticed. Thanks for notifying. Next time for things related to Opera you can ask using the [Opera Bug Wizard](https://bugs.opera.com/wizard/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation for [cookies file format in Opera](http://www.opera.com/docs/operafiles/#cookies) is available again. Thanks David Schiefer to have pinged us.

Comment: No problem. Thanks for getting this sorted out!